# Redirecting output in bash

Tags: bash, redirect

Here's what I am trying to do:

`time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125 && sync"`

When run that on shell the o/p is

```
125+0 records in
125+0 records out
64000 bytes (62.5KB) copied, 0.028935 seconds, 2.1MB/s
real 0m 0.08s
user 0m 0.00s
sys 0m 0.01s
```

I want to capture the output to a variable or to a file. How do I do that ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
(time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125 && sync") 2> file
```

Since you need to redirect the output of both `time` and `dd` you need to enclose the entire thing in `(..)`.

Both `time` and `dd` send their output to stderr, so using `>` will not work, you need `2>` which redirects stderr.

To get the output in a variable you can do:

```
var=$((time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125 && sync") 2>&1)
```

Comment: Thanks but this `var=$((time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125 && sync") 2>&1)` works on ubuntu but not on embedded linux.

Comment: This is what I get:  # var=$((time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125 && sync") 2>&1)     >   >   >   >   >

Comment: I am taken to the bash internal prompt.

Comment: Sorry, my command was mangled. How do you print backticks in SO?

Comment: Basically, try replacing the `$(` with a backtick and the last `)` with another backtick.

Comment: @abc: If `$()` does not work, but backticks do, then it's unlikely that your embedded Linux is using Bash. This is also indicated by the fact that the command in your question uses `sh` which is also not Bash (many `sh` do support `$()` however). Even if `sh` is symlinked to `/bin/bash`, it's run in compatibility mode and should be considered as `sh` (even though some Bash features are available - some are turned off).

Answer (score 2):

Bash uses `>` for standard output redirection. An example would be:

```
./test.sh > outfile.txt
```

If you're interested in appending to rather than replacing outfile.txt, use `>>` instead of `>`. Both redirect standard output.

However, the output of the `time` command in this case will be to standard error, so you must use use `2>` rather than `>`.

```
time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125 && sync" 2> outfile.txt
```

This almost works, but the `time` command works separately from the `sh` shell command, and thus only the output of the `sh` command will be redirected to outfile.txt using the above command. To include the output of the `time` command, we need to wrap the entire command in parenthesis, as below:

```
(time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125 && sync") 2> outfile.txt
```

Comment: @abc, see @codaddict's answer to store the output in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

time sh -c "dd if=/dev/zero of=ddfile bs=512 count=125 && sync" > ./yourfile

> is the redirect command